# Can we use a spring bean within a custom condition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to declare a Spring bean depending on a custom condition. To do so, I have implemented a custom condition and used the @Conditonal annotation on my bean.

My problem is that my custom condition needs to use another bean to do the validation, but the condition is always called before that bean is instantiated. Is there a way to tell Spring to call my custom condition only once that bean is instantiated?

I have tried a couple of things:

1. Use @DependsOn along with @Conditional to force the order of instantiation and try to tell Spring to call the condition after the bean in @DependsOn is instantiated.
2. Use @Lazy on my bean to instantiate it only if needed, thus after the dependant bean is instantiated.
3. Use @ConditionalOnBean with my custom condition.

All of these do not work, my custom condition is called before the dependant bean is instantiated.

Comment: Hi there, I have a felling that this is a case of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Rather than explaining how you want to solve your problem, explain what is the problem you are trying to solve and why you think this is the best way to do so.

Comment: If your custom condition depends on properties, you could use @ConditionalOnProperty